# How do I check whether some matrices have a specific element?

Tags: matlab, matrix, element

So I have, say, 5 different vectors or matrices. I basically want to make an If statement on whether any one of these matrices contains a specific element (e.g. 2), and then display some value (e.g. 8) if any of these matrices does contain this element. It doesn't matter if four of these matrices don't contain the element, if one does then I will display 8.

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB function for 'does matrix contain value X?' (ala php's in\_array())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913670/matlab-function-for-does-matrix-contain-value-x-ala-phps-in-array)

Comment: Not neccesarily a duplicate as this one asks for multiple matrices simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your matrices are A,B,C,D and E. 
Here is a way to check if any of them contains 2.

```
any(A(:) == 2) || any(B(:)== 2) || any(C(:)== 2) || any(D(:)== 2) || any(E(:) == 2)
```

Note the use of `||` instead of `|`, this means that if one matrix is found to contain a 2, it will no longer have to check the other matrices.

An alternate, more compact way to do this (probably less efficient though):

```
any([A(:); B(:); C(:);D(:);E(:)] == 2)
```

From here it should be trivial to display 8 if the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

consider having 5 different matrices named a1, a2, ..., a5

```
if(numel(find(a1==2))|(numel(find(a2==2)))|(numel(find(a3==2)))|(numel(find(a4==2)))|  (numel(find(a5==2))))
display(8)
end
```

you can use any if number of repetitions is not important:

```
if(any(a1(:)==2)|any(a2(:)==2)|any(a3(:)==2)|any(a4(:)==2)|any(a5(:)==2))
display(8)
end
```

Comment: Should get the job done, but especially if the last few matrices are large you will want to avoid evaluating them unless it is neccesary.