# Find a floating point value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, floating-point

When I search for a floating point (decimal) number within a matrix in MATLAB, it does not find it even though it should be there. Specifically, I need to find a number, say `yy = 0.9600`, in the matrices `X` and `Y` but MATLAB does not find them. How to go around this problem?

```
A = reshape(1:10000,100,100).'; %'
p = size(A,1);
B = zeros(p,p);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:p-1,0:p-1); X = X ./ p; Y = Y ./ p;
X = round(X*10000) / 10000;
Y = round(Y*10000) / 10000;
Y = flipud(Y);
for i=1:p,
    for j=1:p,
        x = X(j,i);
        y = Y(j,i);  
        xx = mod((x+y),1);
        yy = mod((x+2*y),1);
        [r, c] = find(X==xx);     %// NOT FOUND
        [rr, cc] = find(Y==yy);   %// "
        a = A(j,i);
        B(rr(1),c(1)) = a;
    end
end
```

Comment: How sure are you that there is that exact number and that it's not a rounding error? I suggest that you apply your rounding to `xx` as well...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to transform an image.  This is the wrong approach for such a problem.  Can you describe your problem to get a few suggestion on a better approach?

Comment: It is very hard to describe it if you have not come across chaotic mapping. It would make more sense if you looked at this pdf file page 1021: http://ict.siit.tu.ac.th/~stanislav/Elementary%20Linear%20Algebra%20with%20Applications.pdf My goal is to create a function that transforms square images using the cat map.

Comment: **See also**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28907857/2778484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do an equality test on a double precision floating point number, see [http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-*0.2*-*0.1*.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to know whether a certain number is in a matrix, I typically use the [`ismemberf` File Exchange Submission](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf).

This basically allows you to check for a value with a certain tolerance, which is required as floating point numbers can be tricky, and 0.9600 may actually be 0.960000000001.

```
%Standard functions
I = find(0.3 == [0:0.1:1]) % Returns an empty matrix
[tf, loc]=ismember(0.3, 0:0.1:1) % returns false 

%Function with a small default tolerance
[tf, loc]=ismemberf(0.3, 0:0.1:1) % returns true
```

---

Basically that is it, but I will add an example of how to get the location to address your comment. Suppose you have a matrix `M` and you want to find the value 7 inside this matrix:

```
% The matrix
M=magic(5)
%Using ismemberf
[tf, loc] = ismemberf(7, magic(5))

%Finding where the value is located:
[I, J] = sub2ind(size(M),loc)
```

Actually you could use `find` here as well. You don't need to worry about rounding issues because you are using the same value twice. Then the last line would look like so:

```
[I,J] = find(M(loc)==M)
```

Note that I would expect `sub2ind` to perform better as it is a simpler function.

Comment: I use Matlab 7.11.0 2010b which does not have ismemberf

Comment: @user3080956 Matlab does not have `ismemberf` by default. But it is offered on the matlab file exchange website that I linked to. Just download the .m file and put it in any directory on your path. http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf

Comment: I need to determine in which row that specific value is.

Comment: @user3080956 Have added an example of how that could be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have done it with integers. I did not divide matrices. Is there a better approach to perform the Cat map transformation? E.g., using repmat or imresize. I would include an image if I had a higher reputation. Could you take a look at this pdf file page 1021 ?http://ict.siit.tu.ac.th/~stanislav/Elementary%20Linear%20Algebra%20with%20Applications.pdf There is a figure showing how the Cat map is done.

Comment: @user3080956 That is different question. I would encourage you to research it a bit yourself, and if you can't figure it out you can ask a new question. Make sure that it is well formulated (including an example and a definition of 'better')

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB **R2015a** added the function [`ismembertol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) that solves this problem.  From the documentation:

> `LIA = ismembertol(A,B,tol)` returns an array containing logical 1 (true) where the elements of `A` are **within tolerance** of the elements in `B`. Otherwise, the array contains logical 0 (false). Two values, `u` and `v`, are within tolerance if
>
> ```
> abs(u-v) <= tol*max(abs([A(:);B(:)]))
> ```
>
> That is, `ismembertol` scales the `tol` input based on the magnitude of the data.

Note that there is also a new `uniquetol` function that [behaves similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27428109/2778484).